# Difference between TweenMax & TweenLite?

Tags: google-chrome, garbage-collection, gsap

Is there any speed or Garbage Collection difference between **`TweenMax`** & **`TweenLite`** ?

Actually currently i'm working on site in which i'm using more than 500 tween with TweenMax , and site works perfectly in firefox but in chrome and safari tween lag very badly.

[Difference between TweenMax & TweenLite based on GC & speed ?](http://forums.greensock.com/topic/10136-difference-between-tweenmax-tweenlite-based-on-gc-speed/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's ***highly*** unlikely you'd notice any performance difference between the two, but technically TweenLite is very *slightly* faster (again, I'd be shocked if it's even slightly noticeable) only because it doesn't have to accommodate quite as many features (like repeat/yoyo). TweenMax has a few more properties, so instances take up a bit more memory. Again, not significant. Both are super optimized for performance and GC shouldn't be an issue for either one.

In the ***VAST*** majority of cases, performance problems have nothing to do with TweenLite or TweenMax - it's graphics rendering in the browser that takes exponentially more horsepower to complete. In other words, JavaScript execution is a small percentage of the overall CPU/GPU drain. You might want to try setting `force3D:true` on tweens to force the target onto its own GPU layer.

My guess is that your Chrome/Safari issues are unrelated to TweenLite/TweenMax but I didn't have time to do a full analysis of your link. I saw that you have some pretty huge "composite layers" events (in excess of 60ms) in the Chrome Dev Tools timeline. The actual JS execution (which is what TweenLite/TweenMax do) looked plenty fast.

Comment: i already follow this answer in your website forum , but again thanks, cheers! (: